# How can I reshape a satellite image in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have satellite image with 3 bands as B2,B3,B4, I want to convert each band to one column. for example B2 band places in first column, B3 band places in second column...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “column” here? Do you mean it in the sense of “table column”, i.e. a collection of features whose properties are 1-band images, or something else? A code sample sketching out how you intend to _use_ this result would probably help clarify.

Comment: actually I want to convert image with 3 bands to 2d array. I didn't use reshape code. I dont know why. I am doing something in earth engine python apı

Comment: I am trying clustering satellite images so I need this